# WordPress new page keeps creating default homepage

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How do I select the option for choosing a specific page I have in my custom WordPress theme folder: `wp-content/themes/my-theme/about.html` to be set as the new page I create?

Every time I create a new page using WordPress it creates the homepage `(index.php)` theme

So I want to create a new page called `About` and I want the page that is to be created `about.html` however instead it creates a new page called `About` but the page is the same as homepage `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

A template for a page with the slug `about` would be `page-about.php`.

Create a template for one Page: For more extensive changes, intended for just one specific Page, you can create a specialized template file, named with that Page's slug or ID:

1. page-{slug}.php
2. page-{ID}.php

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

WordPress's documentation is second to none. Use it!

Comment: Where do I change the link that the `About` page links to?

Answer (score 0):

The highest in template chierachy is page.php, so save your page template you want to set as default as page.php. This shoud do the trick.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-default-page-template

Comment: If I do that, then how would I assign the `About` page to `about.html`